# How can I move text up when inside a span inside of a <li>

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<li>
<a class="dw"><span>Design Goals</span></a>
</li>

.dw {
   background-image: url(/Content/images/icons/fugue/document-globe.png);
}
```

When viewed in my browser I see something like this

```
iii
iii  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
iii  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where i represent the image and x the text "Design goals".

Is there some way that I could push down the background image or push up
the text so that I could get them to line up more. I tried adding padding
and a margin to the span but that does not seem to work. I also tried 
different combination of line-height but that also does not work.

I tried: background-position: center but then it looks like this:

```
             iii
       xxxxxxiiixxxxxx
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Could you provide with a screenshot? It's difficult to understand with the ASCII art..

Comment: how it look like finally please mention....

Comment: try background-position: left center;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position)**.

for example:

```
background-position: center 100px;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't do like I expected at all. I added what this did to my question because I am not sure how to add it in the comment area.

Comment: @Madara -- I know that in some cases w3schools is bad, but in this case background-position is the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/ReqZH/ (bg is pushed up -- change -10px to fe 10px to push it down)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks man !! I didn't know ANYTHING about that (especially that w3c and w3scools are not related!) O_o You made my day :>

Comment: @smefju: The answer is correct, but as long as there's a w3schools link up there, it's not helpful. I'll replace it with an MDN link.

Answer (score 0):

Use Div instead Span because span default display property is inline, div display property is block. If you want to push up the text then give the span tag as first.

Html

```
<li>
<span>Design Goals</span>
<div  class="dw" ><img src='http://wpcdn.padgadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/alphabet.jpg'><div>
</li>
```

css

```
.dw {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/L8HjE/)

In here I split the image so only it comes below to text Or use span display property as block to get down the text and image as first [Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/L8HjE/1/)

Comment: Hi Dinesh. What I have is a 16x16 pixel image and then to the right of it some text in a span. Both of these are contained inside an <a>. The problem is my image is aligned with the top of the li and the text appears to align with the bottom.

Comment: why u use span inside anchor tag(<a>)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the styling to the list element:

```
li {
    background-image: url(http://wpcdn.padgadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/alphabet.jpg);
}

<li><a href="#">Design Goals</a></li>
```